# how to Get Min and Max values in List<map<>> object

Tags: java, collections

Hi i am having the following List> i need to find the Min and max values based on the channel type 
ex:485_0x07="Energy",485_0x08="Energy",485_0x06="Energy"
based on Energy key values

Data Input format is like :

```
[{updatedTime=2017-10-24 23:00:55, 
  playload={"485_0x07":{"Energy":"1750.0","Voltage":"244.83","Current":"0.095795"},
            "485_0x06":{"Energy":"5761.0","Voltage":"244.31","Current":"10.1815"},
            "485_0x08":{"Energy":"2814.0","Voltage":"245.04","Current":"0.469673"},
            "485_0x01":{"Energy":"0.0","Voltage":"0.0","Current":"0.0"}}}, 
 {updatedTime=2017-10-24 23:01:05,
  playload={"485_0x07":{"Energy":"1750.0","Voltage":"244.83","Current":"0.095795"},
            "485_0x06":{"Energy":"5761.0","Voltage":"244.31","Current":"10.1815"},
            "485_0x08":{"Energy":"2814.0","Voltage":"245.04","Current":"0.469673"},
            "485_0x01":{"Energy":"0.0","Voltage":"0.0","Current":"0.0"}}}, 
 {updatedTime=2017-10-24 23:59:49,
  playload={"485_0x07":{"Energy":"1754.0","Voltage":"238.99","Current":"0.100577"},
            "485_0x06":{"Energy":"5762.0","Voltage":"238.04","Current":"10.1387"},
            "485_0x08":{"Energy":"2814.0","Voltage":"238.84","Current":"0.43637"},
            "485_0x01":{"Energy":"0.0","Voltage":"0.0","Current":"0.0"}}}]
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?
Something like storing your values in a `Map` or something.

Comment: @malte hartwig in that each object i have different channel like 485_0x07,485_0x08,485_0x06 in this each channel type i need min and max values of Energy

Answer (score 0):

Without any provided classes, I will just assume you that there is a class for every element in the input. You can try using streams like this:

```
input.stream()
     .flatMap(hbaseObject -> hbaseObject.getPayload().getChannels().stream())
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(channel -> channel.getKey(), 
                                    Collectors.summarizingDouble(channel -> channel.getEnergy()))
```

This will give you a `Map<ChannelKey, DoubleSummaryStatistics>`. The statistics object contains min, max, and average.

Comment: i dont have any class  this values are direly getting form H base tables

Comment: in H base this values will store in the form of json and this channel is not fixed mean one object may contain more channel type also please help me

Comment: It doesn't matter how many channels an object has, that's what the `flatMap` is for: it converts the stream of objects into a stream of all their channels. the groupBy then separates them into different lists based on the channel key, and those list are summarized into those statistics objects. As for input being json, you can [map it into objects](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html).

Comment: Success with that! You could also try to do pattern matching and string splitting to work with the raw strings, but I would strongly recommend using an API to map the Json to objects. It will make for better code and easier maintainance in the long run.